# When do function value and gradient along a curve determine the function in a neighbourhood of the curve?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have two $C^1$ functions $ f, g : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and a curve $c : [0, 1] \rightarrow U $ such that $ f(x) = g(x)$ and $\nabla f(x) = \nabla g(x)$ for all points $x$ on the curve $c$.

Are you aware of any conditions that would imply that $ f(x) = g(x) $ for all $x$ in a small neighbourhood of $c$ ?

In some sense, this would be similar to the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), but ideally without requiring that the functions are analytic and instead knowing some information about the gradient.

Any references are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The condition on its own is untrue. Consider $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $g(x,y) = -x^2 - y^2$. The counterexample is the curve $c(t) = (0,0), \forall t \in [0,1]$. Both these are smooth functions so adding more continuity won't solve it.

If you could show the gradient is the same in some small neighborhood of $c$, then you may have a chance using Taylor Series? For example, given $x$ on the curve and $\epsilon$ small, there exists $\theta \in [0,1]$ such that

$$ f(x + \epsilon) - f(x) = \epsilon^T \nabla f(x + \theta\epsilon) = \epsilon^T \nabla g(x + \theta \epsilon) = g(x + \epsilon) - g(x - \epsilon)  \\ \implies f(x+\epsilon) = g(x + \epsilon)$$

However, I imagine that proving that gradients are equal in a neighborhood is more work than proving the functions themselves are equal in the neighborhood.